# My DNN too accurate ??? How to FIX?

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning

Guys I am new to deep learning. I was training a DNN on [US-Adult Income dataset](http://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/Adult)

Where did I actually go wrong? and another question I want to test my model on a different data set How do I actually do it ?

**This is my code:**

```
import pandas as pd
input_data = pd.read_csv('adult.data.csv')


def label_fix(label):
    if label == '<=50K':
        return 0
    else:
       return 1

input_data['Income'] = input_data['Income'].apply(label_fix)

from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

x_data = input_data.drop('Income',axis = 1)
y_labels = input_data['Income']
X_train,X_test,y_train,y_test = train_test_split(x_data,y_labels,test_size= 0.3,random_state=101)


import tensorflow as tf



Age = tf.feature_column.numeric_column('Age')
Job_class = tf.feature_column.categorical_column_with_hash_bucket('Job-
Class',hash_bucket_size=1000)
fnlwgt = tf.feature_column.numeric_column('fnlwgt')
Education = tf.feature_column.categorical_column_with_hash_bucket('Education',hash_bucket_size=1000)
Education_num = tf.feature_column.numeric_column('Education-num')
Status = tf.feature_column.categorical_column_with_hash_bucket('Status',hash_bucket_size=1000)
Designation = tf.feature_column.categorical_column_with_hash_bucket('Designation',hash_bucket_size=1000)
Marital = tf.feature_column.categorical_column_with_hash_bucket('Marital',hash_bucket_size=1000)
Colour = tf.feature_column.categorical_column_with_vocabulary_list('Colour',['White', 'Asian-Pac-Islander', 'Amer-Indian-Eskimo', 'Other', 'Black'])
Gender = tf.feature_column.categorical_column_with_vocabulary_list('Gender',['Male','Female'])
Capital_gain = tf.feature_column.numeric_column('capital-gain')
Capital_loss = tf.feature_column.numeric_column('capital-loss')
Hours = tf.feature_column.numeric_column('hours-per-week')
Native_country = tf.feature_column.categorical_column_with_hash_bucket('Native-Country',hash_bucket_size=1000)
Income = tf.feature_column.numeric_column('Income')



feats_cols = [Age,Job_class,fnlwgt,Education,Education_num,Status,Designation,Marital,Colour,Gender,Capital_gain,Capital_loss,Hours,Native_country]

model = tf.estimator.LinearClassifier(feature_columns=feats_cols)

input_func = tf.estimator.inputs.pandas_input_fn(x=X_train,y=y_train,batch_size=100,num_epochs=None,shuffle=True)

model.train(input_fn=input_func,steps = 5000)
```

> INFO:tensorflow:Create CheckpointSaverHook.
>   INFO:tensorflow:Saving checkpoints for 1 into C:\Users\micha\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpj2usekuf\model.ckpt.
>   INFO:tensorflow:loss = 69.31474, step = 1
>   INFO:tensorflow:global_step/sec: 149.21
>   INFO:tensorflow:loss = 0.0, step = 101 (0.676 sec)
>   INFO:tensorflow:global_step/sec: 189.379
>   INFO:tensorflow:loss = 0.0, step = 201 (0.528 sec)
>   INFO:tensorflow:global_step/sec: 179.441
>   INFO:tensorflow:loss = 0.0, step = 301 (0.551 sec)
>   INFO:tensorflow:global_step/sec: 170.941
>   INFO:tensorflow:loss = 0.0, step = 401 (0.585 sec)
>   INFO:tensorflow:global_step/sec: 176.699
>   INFO:tensorflow:loss = 0.0, step = 501 (0.574 sec)
>   INFO:tensorflow:global_step/sec: 196.918
>   INFO:tensorflow:loss = 0.0, step = 601 (0.505 sec)
>   INFO:tensorflow:global_step/sec: 186.552
>   INFO:tensorflow:loss = 0.0, step = 701 (0.536 sec)
>   INFO:tensorflow:global_step/sec: 195.329
>   INFO:tensorflow:loss = 0.0, step = 801 (0.515 sec)
>   INFO:tensorflow:global_step/sec: 174.856
>   INFO:tensorflow:loss = 0.0, step = 901 (0.569 sec)
>   INFO:tensorflow:global_step/sec: 176.354
>   INFO:tensorflow:loss = 0.0, step = 1001 (0.562 sec)
>   INFO:tensorflow:global_step/sec: 168.888
>   INFO:tensorflow:loss = 0.0, step = 1101 (0.592 sec)
>   INFO:tensorflow:global_step/sec: 171.54
>   INFO:tensorflow:loss = 0.0, step = 1201 (0.600 sec)
>   INFO:tensorflow:global_step/sec: 171.716
>   INFO:tensorflow:loss = 0.0, step = 1301 (0.573 sec)
>   INFO:tensorflow:global_step/sec: 178.132
>   INFO:tensorflow:loss = 0.0, step = 1401 (0.558 sec)
>   INFO:tensorflow:global_step/sec: 180.651
>   INFO:tensorflow:loss = 0.0, step = 1501 (0.549 sec)
>   INFO:tensorflow:global_step/sec: 175.073
>   INFO:tensorflow:loss = 0.0, step = 1601 (0.580 sec)
>   INFO:tensorflow:global_step/sec: 177.171
>   INFO:tensorflow:loss = 0.0, step = 1701 (0.556 sec)
>   INFO:tensorflow:global_step/sec: 173.214
>   INFO:tensorflow:loss = 0.0, step = 1801 (0.594 sec)
>   INFO:tensorflow:global_step/sec: 165.829
>   INFO:tensorflow:loss = 0.0, step = 1901 (0.586 sec)
>   INFO:tensorflow:global_step/sec: 175.255
>   INFO:tensorflow:loss = 0.0, step = 2001 (0.571 sec)
>   INFO:tensorflow:global_step/sec: 171.048
>   INFO:tensorflow:loss = 0.0, step = 2101 (0.593 sec)
>   INFO:tensorflow:global_step/sec: 181.424
>   INFO:tensorflow:loss = 0.0, step = 2201 (0.548 sec)
>   INFO:tensorflow:global_step/sec: 175.714
>   INFO:tensorflow:loss = 0.0, step = 2301 (0.569 sec)
>   INFO:tensorflow:global_step/sec: 166.801
>   INFO:tensorflow:loss = 0.0, step = 2401 (0.594 sec)
>   INFO:tensorflow:global_step/sec: 173.364
>   INFO:tensorflow:loss = 0.0, step = 2501 (0.580 sec)
>   INFO:tensorflow:global_step/sec: 169.802
>   INFO:tensorflow:loss = 0.0, step = 2601 (0.587 sec)
>   INFO:tensorflow:global_step/sec: 175.314
>   INFO:tensorflow:loss = 0.0, step = 2701 (0.569 sec)
>   INFO:tensorflow:global_step/sec: 172.503
>   INFO:tensorflow:loss = 0.0, step = 2801 (0.585 sec)
>   INFO:tensorflow:global_step/sec: 184.231
>   INFO:tensorflow:loss = 0.0, step = 2901 (0.545 sec)
>   INFO:tensorflow:global_step/sec: 184.926
>   INFO:tensorflow:loss = 0.0, step = 3001 (0.537 sec)
>   INFO:tensorflow:global_step/sec: 189.303
>   INFO:tensorflow:loss = 0.0, step = 3101 (0.526 sec)
>   INFO:tensorflow:global_step/sec: 188.679
>   INFO:tensorflow:loss = 0.0, step = 3201 (0.536 sec)
>   INFO:tensorflow:global_step/sec: 184.756
>   INFO:tensorflow:loss = 0.0, step = 3301 (0.552 sec)
>   INFO:tensorflow:global_step/sec: 184.09
>   INFO:tensorflow:loss = 0.0, step = 3401 (0.534 sec)
>   INFO:tensorflow:global_step/sec: 176.366
>   INFO:tensorflow:loss = 0.0, step = 3501 (0.559 sec)
>   INFO:tensorflow:global_step/sec: 178.401
>   INFO:tensorflow:loss = 0.0, step = 3601 (0.567 sec)
>   INFO:tensorflow:global_step/sec: 192.295
>   INFO:tensorflow:loss = 0.0, step = 3701 (0.523 sec)
>   INFO:tensorflow:global_step/sec: 190.446
>   INFO:tensorflow:loss = 0.0, step = 3801 (0.526 sec)
>   INFO:tensorflow:global_step/sec: 181.776
>   INFO:tensorflow:loss = 0.0, step = 3901 (0.546 sec)
>   INFO:tensorflow:global_step/sec: 174.088
>   INFO:tensorflow:loss = 0.0, step = 4001 (0.577 sec)
>   INFO:tensorflow:global_step/sec: 182.692
>   INFO:tensorflow:loss = 0.0, step = 4101 (0.546 sec)
>   INFO:tensorflow:global_step/sec: 189.383
>   INFO:tensorflow:loss = 0.0, step = 4201 (0.526 sec)
>   INFO:tensorflow:global_step/sec: 183.433
>   INFO:tensorflow:loss = 0.0, step = 4301 (0.556 sec)
>   INFO:tensorflow:global_step/sec: 169.08
>   INFO:tensorflow:loss = 0.0, step = 4401 (0.576 sec)
>   INFO:tensorflow:global_step/sec: 170.028
>   INFO:tensorflow:loss = 0.0, step = 4501 (0.594 sec)
>   INFO:tensorflow:global_step/sec: 173.793
>   INFO:tensorflow:loss = 0.0, step = 4601 (0.574 sec)
>   INFO:tensorflow:global_step/sec: 177.173
>   INFO:tensorflow:loss = 0.0, step = 4701 (0.561 sec)
>   INFO:tensorflow:global_step/sec: 172.853
>   INFO:tensorflow:loss = 0.0, step = 4801 (0.583 sec)
>   INFO:tensorflow:global_step/sec: 179.073
>   INFO:tensorflow:loss = 0.0, step = 4901 (0.561 sec)
>   INFO:tensorflow:Saving checkpoints for 5000 into C:\Users\micha\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpj2usekuf\model.ckpt.
>   INFO:tensorflow:Loss for final step: 0.0.
>   Out[127]:

```
pred_fn = tf.estimator.inputs.pandas_input_fn(x=X_test,batch_size=len(X_test),shuffle=False)

predictions = list(model.predict(input_fn=pred_fn))

final_preds=[]
for pred in predictions:
  final_preds.append(pred['class_ids'][0])

from sklearn.metrics import classification_report

print(classification_report(y_test,final_preds))
```

> ```
>          precision    recall  f1-score   support
>
>      1       1.00      1.00      1.00      9769
> ```
>
> avg / total       1.00      1.00      1.00      9769

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a bug in your method `label_fix`. Because the `<=50K` value is  always prefixed with a space (`<=50K`), `label_fix` will always return 1 resulting in perfect recall and precision. If you fix your method to handle the leading space, you will get more reasonable precision and recalls

```
def label_fix(label):
    if label.strip().strip('.') == '<=50K':
        return 0
    else:
       return 1
```

After fitting your model, you can then use it to predict the income for the `adult.test` data file as follows:

```
test_data = pd.read_csv('adult.test.csv')
test_data['income'] = test_data['income'].apply(label_fix)
y_test_data = test_data['income']
pred_fn = tf.estimator.inputs.pandas_input_fn(x=test_data,batch_size=len(test_data),shuffle=False)
predictions = list(model.predict(input_fn=pred_fn))

final_preds_test_data=[]
for pred in predictions:
  final_preds_test_data.append(pred['class_ids'][0])

print(classification_report(y_test_data,final_preds_test_data))
```

Please note that I had to add `strip('.')` to `label_fix` method as the test file has a slightly different format for the income column:

Comment: How to test my model with a different data set ?

Comment: There is a test set for the US-Adult Income dataset: You could use that that to test your model: http://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/adult/adult.test

Comment: I have it already but I dont know how to use it on the model...How to do it ?

Comment: I have added code to show how to use your model on the test data